# Plesk Migration - Email Problems

Tags: email

Recently did a migration from Plesk 8.x to Plesk 9.x on a different server. Before I do the DNS switch or all domains, I tried to test e-mail send/receive, and there are problems with the email accounts.

There are 244 domains and each client (owner of domain/website) reads e-mails from an e-mail client (outlook,thunderbird).

I have tried sending and receiving e-mails for a specific domain with a new e-mail test account, but SMTP fails. POP3 seems to be working but when trying to send from an e-mail client SMTP authorization fails.

I appreciate any help/tips on this.

Comment: Examining and/or providing the SMTP logs would help greatly.

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue with your SMTP Authentication details,please make sure that SMTP details are correct.